# Cannot find module '@awesome-cordova-plugins/core' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic6

I'm trying to use the in-app browser plugin with Ionic and capacitor. After [Installing and using the plugin as per the documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/in-app-browser), I'm getting the following error:

```
[webpack-dev-server] ERROR
node_modules/@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser/ngx/index.d.ts:1:44 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@awesome-cordova-plugins/core' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { AwesomeCordovaNativePlugin } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/core';
```

Note that I've installed the plugin via:

```
npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/core --save
```

I'm using `Ionic 6.19` with `@capacitor/core 4.6.3` and `angular 15.1.4`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably a CLI issue or bug. I just had to restart the CLI for this to work.

I also noticed that for any of the `awesome-cordova-plugins` to work, you have to first install the core library via `npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/core --save`. I installed this as an afterthought after installing the in-app browser plugin. Probably why I had to restart the CLI.

Answer (score 2):

I Had the same issue in **angular 16 and ionic 6** when trying to prepare android platform...

**Trying**

```
ionic cordova  prepare android
```

**Give Errors**
[image]
**Fixed**
Just try to run below command

```
npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/core --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

Hope it will Help:)